# Accesing an Embedded Derby Database within Weblogic 10g

Tags: weblogic, derby

I have a project call Derby where I have my embedded Derby Database.

My deployment involves multiple projects all packed within an EAR for Weblogic to use. In this EAR I put my Derby project configured for embedded access.

My problem is that the string that I use to access the Derby database references a path in disc. Which is clearly wrong since the EAR is in memory when deployed in weblogic.

Doing a little research I know there is a way to create a datasource to access the derby database in "Network Mode". But that escapes from what I need to do, which is access through embedded mode.

The deployment is built by an ANT script. It compiles and separates the Derby Project in two jars (Java classes that access the Derby Database and the Database itself).

And the question is... How do I access the Derby database within the EAR deployed in my Weblogic?

Answer (score 0):

The EAR may be in memory, but your database is typically still located on disk somewhere. It is possible to use an in-memory Derby database, but any changes you make will not be persistent, so most applications use a disk-resident Derby database.

All of these details are controlled by the URL that you pass when connecting to the Derby engine, so read this to get started: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.9/devguide/cdevdvlp17453.html

Comment: I already read that guide. The problem is that I cannot use an in-memory Database, because it would mean to import all data every time the server restarts.